# Javascript/Typescript generated HTML not showing correctly

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I have tried to make some dynamic HTML. I just want to test if it works and did the following:

```
let context = document.getElementById(anyDivsId);
let h = document.createElement("H1");
let t = document.createTextNode("hello");
let item = h.appendChild(t);
console.log(item);
context.innerHTML = item;
```

The console just logs me the plain Text and the InnerHTML of the Div is also just the plain Text and not a HTML element. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**
I really want to show the h1 not the plain text only.
I already changed the `context.innerHTML` to `context.appendChild`

Comment: You should be appending `t` to `context` instead of `h`. Also, remove the innerHTML line.

Comment: `h` contains `t`, so no, he appends `h`.

Comment: but since he's already appending t, that is probably what you meant to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're setting the value of [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML), it is a string, not a DOM node.

Either do

```
let context = document.getElementById(anyDivsId);
context.innerHTML = "<h1>hello</h1>";
```

Or do..

```
let context = document.getElementById(anyDivsId);
let h = document.createElement("H1");
let t = document.createTextNode("hello");
h.appendChild(t);
context.appendChild(h);
```

Comment: Thank you. The `appendChild` worked but it only appends the text and not the information that it should be a `<h1>`.

Comment: @moessi774 - you should be appending the h1 element since the h1 contains the text. i edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @Pamblam your current post appends h to itself. Can you correct that?

Comment: I already have this. But it is only showing the text no h1 tag or so.

Comment: @moessi774 it was not correct before. it is correct now. see: https://jsfiddle.net/7Lfavsy5/

Comment: @moessi774 - If you didn't notice there was a mistake in my example that was pointed out to me. Try the code after I fixed it. It does append the h1. and you don't need to use both innerHTML and append child. if you use both at the same time then whichever was last is the only one you will see. these two calls contradict each other.

Comment: @Pamblam - Ah now i see. I tried to append the whole chain to the div which was wrong but it felt so logical to me. Thank you for the explaination.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let context = document.getElementById(anyDivsId);
context.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<h1>Hello</h1>');
```

or

```
let context = document.getElementById(anyDivsId);
let h = document.createElement("H1");
h.innerText = 'Hello';
context.appendChild(h);
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work

check the following snippet

```
window.onload=function(){
let context = document.getElementById('anyDivsId');
let h = document.createElement("h1");
let t = document.createTextNode("hello");
let item = h.appendChild(t);
console.log(item);
context.innerHTML = item;
  context.innerText="hello";
}
```

Hope it helps